# empty element when using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to locate the following element using selenium webdriver:

```
<div class="lv-product__details"><div class="lv-product__details-head"><span class="lv-product__details-sku">
            M40712
          </span> <div class="lv-product-add-to-wishlist"><button aria-label="Add to Wishlist" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" class="lv-icon-button lv-product-add-to-wishlist__button"><svg focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" class="lv-icon"><use xlink:href="/_nuxt/icons.svg#sprite-navigation-wishlist-off"></use></svg></button></div></div> <h1 class="lv-product__title">
          Pochette Accessoires
        </h1> <div class="lv-product-variations"><button class="lv-product-variation-selector list-label-l lv-product-variations__selector" aria-expanded="false"><span class="lv-product-variation-selector__title -text-is-medium">
    Material
```

I have tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = "https://en.louisvuitton.com/eng-nl/products/pochette-accessoires-monogram-005656"

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome('path/to/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)

elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("lv-product__details")
```

or via Xpath

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__layout"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]')
```

but the elem is returned as an empty list. is there something that I am doing wrong / can do differently to access the contents of the website?

Comment: Did it work without headless? If it did check the page_source it might detect your a bot and then you'd have to change options to fix that like adding user agents and so on.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan You're right as soon as I set headless to `True` - the `elem` is returned as an empty string. However when `False` it is able to retrieve the element.

Answer (score 1):

### I think you have formated your XPath incorrect

Try this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]')
```

Or this

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("lv-icon-button lv-product-add-to-wishlist__button")
```

And try to import time

```
import time

time.sleep(3) # To make sure everything loads before selenium starts to locate the element
```

Comment: I usually use driver.implicitly_wait(10) too, so try to have that as well

Comment: Thanks for the answer - issue was going headless. Element is able to be retrieved when headless is set to `False`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua = UserAgent()
user_agent = ua.random
print(user_agent)
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
```

All you had to do was add an user agent.

```
M40712
POCHETTE ACCESSOIRES
Material
Monogram Canvas
currently selected
600,00€
Always the epitome of iconic style, this interpretation of the Pochette Accessoires can accommodate a Zippy Wallet. In Monogram canvas, it easily carries all the daily necessities.
Detailed features
23.5 x 13.5 x 4 cm
(Length x Height x Width)
Natural cowhide leather trimmings
Zipper closure
Golden color metallic pieces
See More
PRODUCT CARE
```

Comment: Hi the fake user agent helped however still returned an empty element. I found that it finally worked after I implemented the following options in addition to the fake user agent:

Comment: `options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080"),
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors'),
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content'),
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions"),
options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'"),
options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*"),
options.add_argument("--start-maximized"),
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu'),
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage'),
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox'),
`